# Stored procedure invocation template for ensure transaction (all or nothing)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[usp_SampleProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            EXEC dbo.sp_sp1
            EXEC dbo.sp_sp2
            EXEC dbo.sp_sp3
 
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO dbo.dbErrorLogs (UserName, ErrorNumber, ErrorState, ErrorSeverity, 
                                     ErrorLine, ErrorProcedure, ErrorMessage, ErrorOccuredOn)
        VALUES (SUSER_SNAME(), ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETDATE())
    END CATCH
END
```

In the above stored procedure, there are calls made to sp1, sp2, sp3.

1. Will this template ensure all or nothing behaviour of transactions or do I need to set xact_abort to true?
2. If neither of sp1, sp2, sp3 have transaction concept implemented within them then the rollback on the above template will ensure effect of sp1, sp2, sp3 are reversed. However if there is transaction/commit in say sp2 and say the sp2 results in commit, and say sp3 has an error causing the sample template to perform a rollback. Will this ensure the effect of sp2 is reversed?

Answer (score 0):

XACT_ABORT ON solves the open transaction issue but at the cost of logging implemented in the CATCH block (if you have any).

But "NonexistingTable" type of issues should not be in the production environment. Like why will it deploy an SP using a table that does not exist?
Strange thing. You should have QA in place and your deployment scripts should be verified before running in the production environment.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40078.sql-server-set-xact-abort-vs-try-catch.aspx

IF SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, only that statement which raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues the processing of other statements and it also depends upon the severity of the error, the entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF.

https://sqlskull.com/2020/02/22/sql-server-set-xact_abort/

Comment: Can you give an example of "at the cost of logging implemented in the CATCH block"

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling